# Stilistische Frage mit Beispiel für wissenschaftliche Arbeit

Tags: style

Ich habe häufig Sätze wie diesen, deren Inhalt entweder mit einem oder zwei Kommas geschrieben werden kann:

> Sie erweitern die Architektur um Strukturen, die es ermöglichen, komplexere Analysen durchzuführen.

> Sie erweitern die Architektur um Strukturen, die die Durchführung komplexerer Analysen ermöglichen.

Welcher dieser Sätze wäre stilistisch für eine wissenschaftliche Arbeit besser? Sollte man generell die Variante mit weniger Kommas wählen?

Comment: Wie machen es denn andere wissenschaftliche Arbeiten in deinem Fachbereich?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Voraus: ich kann als Physiker nur die STEM-Seite beurteilen, in den Geistenswissenschaften gelten, glaube ich, ganz andere Regeln.

Erstmal zum konkreten Beispiel: "durchführen" ist ein semantisch schwaches Verb. Der Stil wird allgemein expressiver, wenn man solche Wörter eliminiert:

> Sie erweitern die Architektur um Strukturen, die komplexere Analysen ermöglichen.

Ob das in diesem Fall den Sinn schon zu weit verschiebt, kann ich natürlich nicht beurteilen.

Allgemeiner:

Zu viele substantivierte Verben ("Durchführung") gelten allgemein als schlechter Stil  (Beamtendeutsch) und wirken m.E. nur sehr oberflächlich kompetent. Übermäßiger Gebrauch kann sehr schnell ins Gegenteil umschlagen und unbeholfen-bemüht wirken. Als guter Stil gilt eher eine Sprache, die expressive Verben benutzt. Andererseits wird aber auch Kompaktheit geschätzt. Wo Substantivierung die Satzstruktur klarer und den Satz kürzer macht, ist sie auch erlaubt. Wo sie nur dazu dient, einen eh schon zu komplizierten Satz nicht auftrennen zu müssen, ist sie eher schlecht eingesetzt.

Die Abwägung ist einfach auch Geschmackssache. Wenn du die Möglichkeit hast, die Vorlieben deiner Prüfer kennenzulernen, indem du deren eigene Texte liest, schadet das wahrscheinlich nicht.

Wichtiger als solche stilistischen Details sind aber aus meiner Sicht in wissenschaftlichen Prüfungsarbeiten (die ja letztlich für den Prof geschrieben werden) eine sehr exakte Sprache, ein kompetenter Umgang mit der Fachsprache des jeweiligen Bereichs und eine hohe Dichte eigener Beiträge im Text (- also wenig Literatur-Review, dafür mehr die eigenen Experimente und Daten erörtern).

Comment: Ich habe gelesen, dass die Antwort "nur die STEM-Seite" beurteilt. Das steht auch gleich ganz vorne. Dennoch finde ich, dass dieser Bezug dann im letzten Absatz etwas verloren geht = es hängt doch sehr am Fachbereich, ob überhaupt Experimente existieren. Es gibt auch reine Literatur-Arbeiten - in der Physik vielleicht eher bei den Theoretikern, vielleicht auch erst bei den Master-Theoretikern. Die restlichen Ausführungen halt ich für allgemeingültiger - Aktiv statt Substantivierung.

Comment: @HalvarF Vielen Dank für die Antwort. Würden Sie dann empfehlen, dass ich über meine wissenschaftliche STEM-Arbeit gehe und versuche alle Sätze mit "Durchführung", "Verwendung", "Nutzung" ohne Nominalisierung zu schreiben?

Answer (score 2):

Mein Disclaimer zu normativen Stilfragen:

*Die Frage ist explizit eine normative Frage und fragt nach der stilistischen "Richtigkeit" der beiden Formulierungen. Was ein angemessener Stil ist, kann je nach Textsorte, Sprecherintention und Adressat verschieden sein. Die Vorstellungen von stilistischer Angemessenheit entstehen interaktiv, werden diskursiv verhandelt, und sind dabei oft implizit und nur in Ausnahmefällen kodifiziert - etwa in "Style Guides" für bestimmte Textsorten, etwa für Arbeiten im akademischen Betrieb oder auch entsprechende Richtlinien von Zeitungen für ihre Journalisten.*

*Die normativen Vorstellungen über Sprache sind sehr stark von Autoritäts- und Konventionalitätsargumenten geprägt. Dissens darüber lässt sich nicht restlos mit beschreibenden Methoden auflösen oder klären, und es bleibt immer ein subjektives Moment übrig. Die Akzeptanz bestimmter Autoritäten ist, gerade was Stil angeht, eine Eigenschaft des sozialen Habitus; die stilistische Angemessenheit bestimmter Ausdrücke kann daher gerade je nach sozialem Kontext variieren.*

Dies vorausgeschickt, kann ich hier nur meine persönliche Meinung und mein im akademischen Umfeld erworbenes Stilgefühl anführen. Ich würde sagen: Es hängt vom Kontext ab. Eine auffällige Häufung von Nominalisierungen ("ermöglich die Durchführung von ..." statt "ermöglicht es, ... durchzuführen") wird oft als schlechter Stil wahrgenommen - nichtsdestotrotz ist der Nominalstil in vielen wissenschaftlichen Arbeiten weit verbreitet. Hin und wieder kann es sinnvoll sein, eine Nominalisierung einzufügen. Wenn der Text jedoch vor Nominalphrasen strotzt, würde ich die erste Variante bevorzugen. Oder die Struktur noch weiter vereinfachen und das zu Sagende in mehrere Sätze aufsplitten (das ist häufig eine gute Lösung, wenn die Sätze zu kompliziert werden). Etwa so:

> Die Strukturen X ermöglichen komplexere Analysen. [Sie] erweitern die Architektur um X.

Comment: *Die Frage stellt eine Frage und fragt ...* so viel zum Thema Stil.

Comment: @Olafant Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob ich den Kommentar richtig verstehe. Du meinst, meine Antwort ist stilistisch misslungen?